# how to get url value from arduino using ajax and laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, arduino

this is my url value from arduino
request_string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/monitoring/x/?x=1";

i have problem when try to catching the value using url in ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/monitoring/x/',
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response){
          if (response.data==0) {

             var img = document.getElementById("kursi7");
             img.src="{{asset('/assets/images/kursi.jpg')}}";
            document.getElementById('lokasi'+1).innerHTML=("TIDAK ADA ORANG");
          }else {
            // location.reload();
            var img = document.getElementById("kursi7");
            img.src="{{asset('/assets/images/kursi_booked.jpg')}}";
            document.getElementById('lokasi'+1).innerHTML=("ADA ORANG");
          }
        }
        });
```

and processing in php (laravel)
i have some error undefined variable x when try to get the data $_GET['x'] from passing value url in arduino

```
public function data(Request $req, $x)
{
  $x=$_GET['x'];
  
  return response()->json($x);
}
```

i hope someone can help and give me an information abt this.
thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP side of things you should be doing something like this instead:

```
public function data(Request $request)
{
  $x = $request->input('x')
  
  return response()->json($x);
}
```

As per https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request